# Prove $T:l^1\rightarrow \mathbb C \quad T(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} x_n $ is continuous and calculate the norm

Tags: real-analysis

An operator is continuous if is bounded: in fact

$|Tx|=|\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} x_n|\le \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} |x_n|=||x||_1$

The norm of the operator is :

$||T||=\sup_{x\in l^1,x\ne0} \frac{|Tx|}{||x||_1}=1$?

If I consider $X=(l^1,||.||_2)$ the operator $T: X \rightarrow \mathbb C$ is not continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not. If it is continuous there would be a constant $C$ such that $|\sum x_n| \leq C\sqrt {\sum |x_n|^{2}}$ for all $(x_n)\in \ell^{1}$. Apply this to $(1,\frac  1 2,...,\frac 1 N,0,0...)$ to see that $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{N} \frac  1 k $ remains bounded as $N \to \infty$. This is a contradiction so $T$ is not continuous.

Comment: Why remains bounded?

Comment: Because $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{N} \frac  1 {k^{2}} \leq \frac {\pi^{2}} 6$ for all $N$.

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac{1}{k}$ is not bounded

Comment: That is exactly the contradiction.

Comment: The calculus of the norm up is right?

Comment: Yes,it is correct